# Is this matrix positive?

Tags: matrices

for each t between 0 and 1 I have a matrix A(t) that is positive.

is $\int_0^1 A(t) dt$ positive, too ?

Comment: What's your definition of a positive matrix?

Comment: The usual definition : positive or null eigenvalues.

Comment: Is the function $t\rightarrow At$ continous?

Comment: if positive matrix means positive definite, it is true,

Comment: Yes it is the Hessian of a C2 function

Comment: I just figured it I think, we can move the scalar product in the definition of positive definiteness inside in the integral, so we are integrating a positive function so we don't need continuity of t -> At ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Integrability is enough.

Comment: The "usual" term is **positive semi-definite**. Matrices with only positive entries are also called positive.